# How to place two existing columns under a hierarchy?

Tags: pandas

Given the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(randn(10, 5), columns=['a', 'b1', 'b2', 'c1', 'c2'])
```

How can I add another hierarchy level to the columns that would bind 'b1' and 'b2' under 'b', and 'c1', 'c2' under 'c'?

I've only found examples for generating a hierarchical index in a new dataframe.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by defining a MultiIndex (consisting of the original column labels and a new level) and assigning this to the columns (overwriting the existing columns):

```
In [73]: upper_level = [i[0] for i in df.columns]

In [74]: df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([upper_level, df.columns])

In [75]: df
Out[75]:
          a         b                   c
          a        b1        b2        c1        c2
0 -1.656965  1.838595 -1.745855 -2.024337  0.087243
1  0.573167  0.946658  0.691831 -1.107968 -0.911961
2  0.279150  0.038185  0.970203 -0.129443  0.977402
3 -1.192675  2.103922 -1.170816  1.433252  0.251258
4  1.465639  1.925409 -0.759904  1.062088  0.555272
5 -0.667394 -0.941874  0.192990  0.787811 -1.236446
6 -0.016380 -0.106379 -1.328149 -0.576587  0.269650
7 -1.040711 -0.156927  0.056562 -1.073571  0.899144
8 -0.962474  0.505168  0.348957  1.640170 -0.376509
9 -0.431045  0.228514 -1.447591  0.058036  0.126517
```

In this case, I made the new index level by taking the first character of the original columns, but of course you can apply another function here if wanted.